# How we decide the region of computing SIFT Descriptor?

Tags: image, sift, feature-extraction

A keypoint descriptor is created by first computing the gradient magnitude and orientation
at each image sample point in a region around the keypoint location. But i confused about the meaning of "region". what is the size of it? depends on the keypoint's magnitude ? or kernel size of Gaussian in the scale level which the keypoint found ? or else ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on "kernel size of Gaussian in the scale level" - in sense "what region from original image we take". 
Also it depends on SIFT parameter - PatchSize (usually=41) to which size window in pixels we reproject region from the original image.

Comment: According to David Lowe article, the region from which we extract the SIFT descriptor vector has the size of 16 by 16 pixels. But I'm a little bit confused since i've seen this region varying differently as in [here](http://www.aishack.in/wp-content/uploads/2010/06/sift-result.jpg)